# How to decide if traps in OSR play should be obvious?

Tags: encounter-design, adventure-writing, osr, traps, dungeon-design

Obvious traps emphasize interaction with the traps, which is often interesting.

Hidden traps make unexplored regions of a dungeon far more dangerous and reward careful play and cunning, as players might guess where traps are.

Hence, there is a trade-off between different kinds of interesting play, at least. Doubtless there are other trade-offs and considerations.

**What factors do I use to decide if I make traps obvious or inobvious?**

---

In this OSR play means specifically challenge-focused, player-driven sandbox play, where the challenges are primarily set up in terms of the fiction and not as rules-level challenges, which are typically simple. Consensus rules.

- Challenge: Players play to defeat fictional challenges. Typical goal is to acquire gold pieces.
- Player-driven: Players decide which challenges to tackle. Players and dice together decide the failure or success of their endeavours; the referee does not make calls to influence the success of player characters or the challenges faced by them, but arbitrates the events of play and the state of fiction.
- Sandbox: There are a number of adventures which the players can engage with. There can be essentially impassable obstacles and essentially undefeatable challenges, since the players can adventure somewhere else, if something is too difficult for them.
- Challenges are not rules-level: A corridor with a green slime, or a hungry giant, are the challenges. The mechanical representation of the challenges is incidental (and we can agree to change it as a group if it does not make sense).
- Consensus rulings: Rules and rulings must be acceptable to everyone and they are made solely to represent the fiction and reveal the challenges inherent to it. Anyone can suggest a rules interpretation. (Sometimes the referee can ask for trust, since there is hidden information, but such trust has to be earned.)

To me it is not a factor if thieves (or some other particular class of characters) have or do not have an opportunity to use their abilities. I play with homebrew rules as often as with more well-known ones and good dungeon design practices transcend rules systems. It is up to players to make their characters useful or not.

---

In a good answer I expect a list of factors which influence the decision to make traps generally obvious. I listed two examples above and listed one non-example.

Comment: “How do I decide” tends to be a good question pattern. I don't see any reason this would be off topic as currently written.

Comment: I think this is still Primarily Opinion-based, or possibly Too Broad; How traps should be used depends entirely on the group' preferred playstyle and focus of play, and the social contract, and how the specific system handles traps, and even within the space of OSR games there's a lot of variation in all of those things - and as this question is currently written, a good answer would have to cover *all* the possibilities.

Comment: @GMJoe Does the new explanation of this strand of OSR play suffice?

Comment: @Thanuir I'm not sure. On the one hand, your dot points do provide some useful guidelines that would apply to placing traps; On the other hand, the amount of forewarning a given trap should have is still hugely dependant on the groups' preferences. I honestly don't know if this is narrow-scoped enough to be a good fit to this site... So I'll leave it up to others to decide whether this question should be re-opened.

Answer (score 6):

Findable ... yes; obvious ... it depends.

If you're playing true old school then the players must find the traps, there is no perception roll. Therefore there must be clues to enable them to find them. How obvious you make the clues depends on the purpose of the trap and the intention of the person who put it there.

Some "traps" like a moat or a field with "Warnung! Minen!" signs are and are meant to be blindingly obvious because they are there to tell people to go away.

Others are meant to injure the person who triggered it or set of an alarm for the benefit of the person who set it. These will be ... less obvious *but* there should be clues that players who are paying attention to the description you give can pick up on.

For example a fire trap may have scorched the walls or have vents or have left behind crispy critters or whatever is needed to get the players to prick up their ears and say "Wait a minute ...". And then, *every* fire trap in the complex should give the same clues (except the critters these should draw your attention to the vents then the vents should be enough); so the first fire trap they find if they are paying attention (or they set it off) subsequent ones they find because they know what to look for; this makes them feel clever.

Also, remember that what lives here has to live with the trap. Intelligent creatures don't put traps between their bedrooms and the latrines because the first time you sleepily go for a slash in the middle of the night ...

For theory and examples of this try http://hackslashmaster.blogspot.com.au/p/trick-trap-index.html.

Comment: +1 "Warnung! Minen!" is probably the garbliest Mock German I have ever seen.

Comment: @eimyr that's because it's Kobold, what's "German"?

Answer (score 0):

The most important factor, is what is fun. Things that are fun:

- solving a puzzle, beating up bad guys, acquiring treasure, etc.

Things that are not fun:

- getting all the hard work and character growth reduced to nothing by a trap that comes out of nowhere. Stupid [sphere of annihilation](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Sphere_of_Annihilation)...

So, the key factor you need to consider, is whether the player knows to expect traps. If your dungeon is called "the infamous trap-filled dungeon of the trap wizard" then yeah, stuff it full of all kinds of traps - both obvious and hidden. On the other hand, the castle of the infamous warlord "Brutal Bruce the Brainless Barbarian" should NOT be full of hidden traps.

The second thing to bear in mind, is that the players need both clues to discover the traps, and a way around them. So it's ok for traps to be hidden, as long as it is reasonable to expect them to be there, like an important looking door, or an inscription on the wall warning people away, or a local barkeep saying "gnolls like to hide their traps" or something. Triggering a hidden trap on the door to the treasure room is completely reasonable. Falling into a spike pit while crossing the town square, less so.

The basic idea being, traps are challenges for your players to overcome, which means that they players need to be able to overcome them - which means, having some way of knowing they are there. Otherwise you are just being annoying.

Hiding traps is fine, as long as the reaction they cause in the player is "my bad, should have guessed that would be there" and not "no fair! you're just trying to kill us". So it needs to be obvious that there ARE (or could be) traps, but it does not need to be obvious WHERE they are.

**TL;DR:** Traps need to contribute to the game - and to the fun of the game. So traps should be hidden when players know to expect hidden traps, and/or when triggering the trap will not ruin the game.

Comment: Old school play, so players better expect traps (in general). Also, search DC is not a typically used rules mechanic in old school play.

Comment: Yeah, this answer doesn't sound like it's from an OSR playstyle to me.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, you're right - this is really not old school style. Sorry, I didn't think to check the tags. Should I delete this as not relevant?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast ok, I've revised it